# What's visible in a ScrollViewer?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a `GridView`. I am using the nested `ScrollViewer`'s `SnapPoints` to snap each record into view. Because this is only a visual change, and not a data change, how can I determine which record(s) is currently visible? Something like `SelectedItem`, but a visual query. I could check every record, but it seems inefficient. Ideas?

Comment: Do you need something that is actually visible or would it be enough to get things that are virtualized in (have `GridViewItems` representing them currently)?

Comment: Funny thing is - I actually need that same functionality today (tonight). I might work on an extension method...

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Nothing great. For now I simply call the `GetDescendantsOfType<>()` extension method from my toolkit which uses `VisualTreeHelper` to grab all elements of a given type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could use the `VisualTreeHelperExtensions` from WinRT XAML Toolkit and do something like this

```
gridView
    .GetDescendantsOfType<GridViewItem>()
    .Select(gvi => gridView.ItemFromContainer(gvi));
```

It does a somewhat intensive visual tree search, but might be OK for your scenario if your `GridView` uses virtualization since the items returned are in or near the view port. If you want to be more precise you can test for bounding rect intersections. Something like this might be enough:

```
static class RectExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsPartOf(this Rect bigRect, Rect smallRect)
    {
        // this is a very targeted test for horizontally scrollable smallRects inside of a bigRect
        return bigRect.Left < smallRect.Left && bigRect.Right > smallRect.Left ||
               bigRect.Left < smallRect.Right && bigRect.Right > smallRect.Right;
    }
}

var sv = gridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
var bigRect = new Rect(0, 0, sv.ActualWidth, sv.ActualHeight);

gridView
    .GetDescendantsOfType<GridViewItem>()
    .Where(gvi => bigRect.ContainsPartOf(gvi.GetBoundingRect(sv)))
    .Select(gvi => gridView.ItemFromContainer(gvi));
```

Comment: In that scenario, why not just use Items? Or cast ItemsSource if you are binding?

Comment: Well, if your list is virtualized, then the `GridViewItems` in the visual tree are in or near the viewport, so they are essentially almost the same as "currently visible". If you need to see which are in the visual tree - you can grab their bounding rects and see if they are within the view port.

Comment: I wish it were easier